# Building and animating fractals

Tags: animation, fractals, mandelbrot

Can anyone recommend any software/books required to learn and build fractal patterns? I want to also be able to animate the fractal patterns too. Like something off of winamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of fractal programs out there.

I know that Ultrafractal is pretty popular, but not free.

As far as free ones go, there are programs such a ChaosPro and others. A quick google search will find them for you.

Answer (score 2):

For book on animated fractal [Fractals: An Animated Discussion with Edward Lorenz and Benoît Mandelbrot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000P8FIEK)  could be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might like: The Computational Beauty of Nature 
http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/flaoh/cbnhtml/

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project in java for creating fractals (flame fractals).
The user provides a script file in javascript, that takes care of the interpolation between fractals. Also, as input, one can provide a file that affects an animation in some way,
so this is the way to make an animation change to some music,
see for example
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imDPqR9cDL8

I can send you the source code if you provide me with an address.